# Does File.WriteAllText really throws a FileNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, file, filenotfoundexception

Documentation says:

```
// Summary:
//     Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes
//     the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.
```

First line, first sentence: `Creates a new file`, and on the exceptions it lists:

```
//   System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
//     The file specified in path was not found.
```

In which case would this happen? If it always create a file then it shouldn't thrown a FileNotFoundException...

Is the documentation wrong? Or is it missing a `<remarks>` tag perhaps?

Comment: What if part of the path is not found. Would that be a `FileNotFoundException` or `DirectoryNotFound`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders that is a `DirectoryNotFoundException`: `{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\ZZZZZZ\\ZZZ\\TEST.txt'."}`

Comment: It is a copy-paste bug from the File.ReadAllText() article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File.WriteAllText` eventually calls:

```
private static void InternalWriteAllText(string path, string contents, Encoding encoding)
{
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(contents);
    }
}
```

All of the exceptions thrown prior to the call to `InternalWriteAllText` throw `ArgumentException` or `ArgumentNullException` but theoretically (since `FileStream` can throw the exception) the `streamWriter.Write(contents);` could potentially throw the exception. Very unlikely though based on what it does and how the `streamWriter` is opened.

I wouldn't necessarily say the doc is *wrong* per se, more that MS is covering their butt by documenting the (very rare) possibility.

Source: Decompiling `mscorlib` v4.0.0.0 using ILSpy.

**UPDATE**

Just checked `mscorlib` v2.0.0.0, same case except it contains fewer sanity checks (meaning it basically translates directly to the code above).